# How to get rid of warning when overriding MPMoviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am trying to override the currentPlaybackTime property of the MPMoviePlayerController class. I declared the following in the header file of my subclass of MPMoviePlayerController.

```
@interface MyMoviePlayerController : MPMoviePlayerController {
}

@property(nonatomic, getter=getCurrentPlaybackTime, setter=setCurrentPlaybackTime) 

- (NSTimeInterval) getCurrentPlaybackTime;
- (void) setCurrentPlaybackTime:(NSTimeInterval)newValue;

@end
```

I am getting two warning messages as shown below:

```
warning: property 'currentPlaybackTime' 'setter' attribute does not match super class 'MPMoviePlayerController' property

warning: property 'currentPlaybackTime' 'getter' attribute does not match super class 'MPMoviePlayerController' property
```

The override actually works but is there a way to suppress the annoying warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to remove your own getter/setter and use the default ones

```
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval currentPlaybackTime;
```

and use

```
- (NSTimeInterval) currentPlaybackTime;
```

instead of

```
- (NSTimeInterval) getCurrentPlaybackTime;
```

thats the default getter and setter and you have not to set your own.